Covariance of multivariate O-U process
Let $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a multivariate OU process, i.e it satisfies:
$$
dX_t = -A(t) X_t \mathrm{d}t + B(t) \mathrm{d}W_t
$$
where $W_t$ is an $M$-dimensional independent Brownian motion, $A: T \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ and $B: T \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times M}$. I found the expectation of this process to be
$$
\mathbb{E} [X_t] = \exp \bigg( - \int_0^t A(s) \mathrm{d} s \bigg) \mathbb{E} [X_0]
$$
I now need to calculate the covariance of the process. The hint given is to first apply Ito's formula to $X_t X_t^T$ and take expectations. Doing so:
$$ \mathrm{d} (X_t X_t^T) = (\mathrm{d} X_t) X_t^T + X_t (\mathrm{d} X_t^T) + (\mathrm{d} X_t)(\mathrm{d}X_t^T)
$$
Expanding this out and integrating, I got:
$$
X_t X_t^T = X_0 X_0^T + \int_0^t \bigg( -A(s)X_sX_s^T - X_s X_s^T A(s) + B(s)B(s)^T \bigg) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t B(s) \mathrm{d}W_s X_s^T + \int_0^t X_s \mathrm{d}W_s^T B(s)^T
$$
I don't see how taking expectations can help in calculating the required $\mathbb{E}[X_t X_t^T] - \mathbb{E}[X_t]\mathbb{E} [X_t]^T$. I would appreciate any pointers, correction and/or hints to continue.

Please say that O-U = Ornstein-Uhlenbeck...

The notation $$\int_0^t B(s) \mathrm{d}W_s X_s^T + \int_0^t X_s \mathrm{d}W_s^T B(s)^T$$ is awful.

As recommended by your hint, take the expectation of the SDE provided by Itô's lemma. Then, you will face an inhomogeneous first-order linear ODE for the quantity $\Bbb{E}[X_tX_t^T]$, namely
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Bbb{E}[X_tX_t^T] = -A(t)\Bbb{E}[X_tX_t^T] - \Bbb{E}[X_tX_t^T]A(t) + B(t)B(t)^T,
$$
which is solved by
$$
\Bbb{E}[X_tX_t^T] = \alpha(t)\left(\Bbb{E}[X_0X_0^T] + \int_0^t \alpha(s)^{-1}B(s)B(s)^T\alpha(s)^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}s\right)\alpha(t),
$$
where $\alpha(t)$ is the solution to the differential equation $\dot{\alpha} = -A\alpha$.
It is important to highlight that the latter matrix $\alpha$ is not trivial (because of the properties of the derivative of the exponential map) and corresponds to $\alpha(t) = \exp\left(-\int_0^t A(s) \,\mathrm{d}s\right)$ in particular cases $-$ when $A$ is a scalar/diagonal matrix or it commutes with its derivative $\dot{A}$. In consequence, your solution for $\Bbb{E}[X_t]$ is not correct either and should be replaced in general by $\Bbb{E}[X_t] = \alpha(t)\Bbb{E}[X_0]$ with the same mentioned matrix $\alpha$.
